# Binding a ListView Label to a property

Tags: xaml, xamarin

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:TestApp.ViewModels"
         x:Class="TestApp.Views.MasterPage"
         Title="This is the title">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="listView">
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type viewModels:MasterPageItem}">
                    <viewModels:MasterPageItem Title="{Binding Item1}"/>
                    <viewModels:MasterPageItem Title="{Binding Item2}"/>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalTextAlignment="End"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

So I'm get a build error: "No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Title', or mismatching type between value and property." I'm trying to bind the MasterPageItem Title property to a value in my view (this is being done so I can translate values during runtime via a selection for desired language). Item1 and Item2 are properties that live in the MasterPage view, while Title lives in the MasterPageItem. The Label in the ListView is being bound to the MasterPageItem Title property.

I'm not really sure what exactly I'm doing wrong here so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this `MasterPageItem` refers to the class commonly created to handle menu selection when adding a `MasterDetailPage` on your project, it hasn't `BindableProperty` indeed.

This is the default model we use:

```
public class MainPageMenuItem
{
    public MainPageMenuItem()
    {
        TargetType = typeof(MainPageDetail);
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Type TargetType { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to use binding you'll have to make this class a `BindableObject` and then change its property to bindable ones.

Like this:

```
public class MainPageMenuItem : BindableObject
{
    public MainPageMenuItem()
    {
        TargetType = typeof(MainPageDetail);
    }

    public readonly static BindableProperty IdProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Id), typeof(int), typeof(MainPageMenuItem));
    public int Id
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(IdProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IdProperty, value); }
    }

    public readonly static BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Title), typeof(string), typeof(MainPageMenuItem));
    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public readonly static BindableProperty TargetTypeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TargetType), typeof(Type), typeof(MainPageMenuItem));
    public Type TargetType
    {
        get { return (Type)GetValue(TargetTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TargetTypeProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This resolved the error, but the value still isn't showing in the list view.

Comment: @tldragoon so make sure `Item1` and `Item2` has content and/or is notifying changes. You have to check if the `BindingContext` of each `viewModels:MasterPageItem` in your array is being set as you are expecting.

Comment: So the notifications are coming through (the properties are being called when changed). I'm not exactly sure how I check the BindingContext though...

Comment: Here you are doing a binding: `viewModels:MasterPageItem Title="{Binding Item1}"` right? Where did this `Item1` come from? Is it in the page's viewmodel?

Comment: Right now I just have it in the page's .cs file

Comment: So change the item's declaration to `<viewModels:MasterPageItem BindingContext={Binding BindingContext, Source={Reference listView}} Title="{Binding Item1}"/>`. Assuming the `listView`'s BindingContext is the page where the `Item1` property is.

Comment: Sorry for it being one issue after another. I'm really new to Xamarin... I get a XamlParseException "Can not find the object referenced by  'listView':

Comment: So try put a fixed text on the title. If it works, we'll need to handle the binding problem you are facing in another thread. Maybe another one can see what I'm missing, and sure you'll have to provide a [mcve]